# Inheritance, does the "is a" relationship always have to hold?

Tags: oop, inheritance, subtype

If class B inherits from class A, does class B always have to be a sub-type of A when used in inheritance?

I am thinking if it is possible to use inheritance to provide extra code to B, when B is not a subtype of A?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: If class A is providing extra code to class B, then by very definition, B is a subtype of A.

Comment: If B inherits from A how could it not be a sub-type of A, that's the definition of inheritance! Maybe B could get emancipated from A :-)

Comment: Are you asking if it is _okay_ to have B derive from A when B is not an A (fails [Liskov's substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle))? -- Perhaps you're looking for [mixins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin)?

Comment: Yes, it does.  Some languages such as C# and Ruby allow you to bolt on additional functionality without regard to inheritance.  I believe what you are looking for is *duck typing.*

Answer (score 0):

If type `A` inherits from `B`, that means two things:

1. Class `A` will be able to use public and protected static methods from class `B`, without having to specify the class name, and objects of class `A` will implicitly include all public and protected class members from `B` without having to respecify them.

   Any code accepting objects of type `B` will, at at compile time, accept objects of type `A`, and objects of class `A` will be able to use class `B`'s public and protected instance methods on themselves.

Interfaces essentially embody concept #2 but not #1 (since interfaces have no static methods, and have no members that can be used implicitly without having to specify them).  There is no built-in way to achieve #1 without #2; the only significant benefit of having #1 without #2 would be to save typing.

Answer (score 0):

If:

```
class B extends A
```

Than `B` is by definition a subtype of `A`.

If you don't want that, you can use PHP's **[traits](http://il.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php)**, which is basically **interfaces** with implementation.